# Calculating Margin from Two Tables SQL

Tags: sql, vba

So I am running into an issue that I have isolated to part of the WHERE statement and I can't figure it out.  I am calculating margin for an item based on the cost and price tables associated with it. It works fine if I want to limit it to items whose list price is below 17%, but if I want to check the other price tiers, e.g. pricing if a customer buys +100 units, I get an ODBC error. This is my code that doesn't work:

```
            strSQL = "SELECT IMFGR || ICOLOR || IPATT as Item, INAME as Description1, INAME2 as Description2,  IPRCCD as PClass, ICSTCD as CClass, " _
               & "c.TLASTC as Cost, p.$LIST as List, ((p.$LIST-c.TLASTC)/p.$LIST) as GPM, p.$P2 as Price2, ((p.$P2-c.TLASTC)/p.$P2) as GPM2, " _
               & "p.$P3 as Price3, ((p.$P3-c.TLASTC)/p.$P3) as GPM3, p.$P4 as Price4, ((p.$P4-c.TLASTC)/p.$P4) as GPM4, p.$P5 as Price5, ((p.$P5-c.TLASTC)/p.$P5) as GPM5, " _
               & "p.$P6 as Price6, ((p.$P6-c.TLASTC)/p.$P6) as GPM6, p.$P7 as Price7, ((p.$P7-c.TLASTC)/p.$P7) as GPM7, p.$P8 as Price8, ((p.$P8-c.TLASTC)/p.$P8) as GPM8, " _
               & "p.$P9 as Price9, ((p.$P9-c.TLASTC)/p.$P9) as GPM9, p.$P10 as Price10, ((p.$P10-c.TLASTC)/p.$P10) as GPM10, p.$P11 as Price11, ((p.$P11-c.TLASTC)/p.$P11) as GPM11, " _
               & "p.$P12 as Price12, ((p.$P12-c.TLASTC)/p.$P12) as GPM12 " _
               & "FROM ITEM i " _
               & "LEFT JOIN COST c " _
                    & "ON i.ICSTCD = c.TCSTCD " _
               & "LEFT JOIN PRICE p " _
                    & "ON i.IPRCCD = p.$PRCCD " _
               & "WHERE (IPRCCD != '') AND (p.$LIST# = 'LP') AND (IPOL1 != 'DI' AND IPOL2 != 'DI' AND IPOL3 != 'DI') AND (IPOL1 != 'BR' AND IPOL2 != 'BR' AND IPOL3 != 'BR') AND (IMFGR = '" & man & "') AND " _
               & "((ICCTR != 'ZDS') AND (IPRODL != 'XXX')) AND " _
               & "((p.$LIST-c.TLASTC)/p.$LIST) <= '" & margin & "' OR ((p.$P2-c.TLASTC)/p.$P2) <= '" & margin & "' " _
               & "ORDER BY IMFGR"
```

The OR in the second to last line generates the error. If I change it to AND, it runs but then it looks for both statements to be true. I want to return a result if any of the margins are below a certain %. What am I doing wrong?

It isn't the p.$LIST# = 'LP' because the p.$p2, p.$p3, etc. are still in there with 'LP'

Comment: Shouldn't `margin` be unquoted? Is it numeric?

Comment: Sounded like a promising suggestion, but after making sure the output of margin was being converted to a number from a string, I still get the same results. Works fine until the OR is added then ODBC error.

Comment: What is the error that you get?  Is it always the same error?

Comment: I am running this with VBA and the error is always the same: "Run-time error '1004': General ODBC Error. I usually get this if I spell a column header wrong or something, but the info is correct. It is just the OR portion that is causing issue.

Comment: Actually, it is not just the OR. I removed this portion and still ran into the error. But it runs when it is both portions and the AND... WTH? `((p.$LIST-c.TLASTC)/p.$LIST) <= '" & margin & "' OR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AND has precedence over OR.  You need to wrap the OR clause in parens:

```
  & "(((p.$LIST-c.TLASTC)/p.$LIST) <= '" & margin & "' OR ((p.$P2-c.TLASTC)/p.$P2) <= '" & margin & "') " _
```

Comment: Yea, tried that as well and still get an ODBC error.